# Highlight selected item in the dropdown in flutter

Tags: flutter

How can I highlight a selected item in the dropdown? Currently, when the dropdown items open up, the already selected item is not understandable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `selectedItemBuilder` parameter in the `DropdownButton` as follow:

```
DropdownButton<String>(
      value: dropdownValue,
      onChanged: (String? newValue) {
        setState(() {
          dropdownValue = newValue!;
        });
      },
      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
      selectedItemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
        return options.map((String value) {
          return Text(
            dropdownValue,
            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          );
        }).toList();
      },
      items: options.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: value,
          child: Text(value),
        );
      }).toList(),
    ),
```

also, you can change the style of different options using `items` parameter as is clear in the above example. For more info see [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton/style.html).

Comment: @Anoop.P.A did my answer help you?

Comment: No @Abbasihsn, the selected item is still not highlighted when I open up the dropdown. Maybe because the dropdown item in my app is not a simple text widget but a complicated widget. But Thank you for your answer

Comment: oh, I just give it as an example! please try other widgets like Container with any background color you want! you can use any other widget instead of Text!!! feel free to ask any question related to that